# Hoverfly - capturing request & responses for micro services

Tags: proxy, hoverfly

I am trying to capture request & response from an application using Hoverfly. The Hoverfly is installed on a machine and set to proxy with capture mode.

The application is a web application deployed in Weblogic in linux box. The application internally uses soap requests to communicate to a Tibco ESB server and fetch details from provider systems. I want to capture the soap requests & responses between application server & ESB.

To capture the request & response I have set proxy on the application server in following ways:

1) Add the proxy parameters in setDomianEnv.sh script of application server
    EXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES="-Dhttp.proxyHost=10.0.0.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8500 ${EXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES}"
    export EXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES

2) add the proxy parametes in JVM startup parameters of application

3) set proxy for os level user
    http_proxy=http://10.0.0.1:8500

In all the three cases I have failed to capture requests & responses in Hoverfly.

Are there any other ways to do the same or any additional settings to be done to route the request & response through the proxy?

Answer (score 0):

That should be sufficient. Is your SOAP service HTTP or HTTPS ? if HTTP this should work. If HTTPS you need to add the self signed Hoverfly certificate to your Weblogic JVM truststore (jre/lib/security/cacerts) to be able to capture those HTTPS requests. Also in case of HTTPS communication, the JVM args should be -Dhttps.proxyPort and -Dhttps.proxyHost

In my opinion, OS level proxy is not required as long as the JVM parameters are set.

Make sure Hoverfly is running and in the Hoverfly Dashboard page, you should set it in Capture mode and when you invoke the services from your Weblogic server, the Capture count in Hoverfly Dashboard should increase. And that's a sign of everything is working.